# How can I loop through my entries to export them using Beam?

Tags: templating, plugins

I want to export my entries to CSV or JSON.  Craft 2 had a plugin.  I can't find one for Craft 3.

**I reached out to the Craft community on Slack.  They suggested I try the Craft 3 plugin Beam.**

I was told it should be trivia. But, the [documentation on Beam](https://superbig.co/plugins/beam) is light.

This is the example provided in the Beam documentation to export to CSV:

```
{% spaceless %}
{% set options = {
header: ['Email', 'Name'],
rows: [
      [ 'test@example.com', 'John Doe' ],
      [ 'another+test@example.com', 'Jane Doe' ],
      [ 'third+test@example.com', 'Trond Johansen' ], 
]
} %}
{{ craft.beam.csv(options) }}
{% endspaceless %}
```

I want the `header` to be the field names used in an entry and the `rows` to be values for each entry in my `posts` section.

I can't use a loop in the option settings.  **So, how do I set the options to loop through the entries fields and values?**

Thanks

Comment: Sprout Reports is NOT an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing... obviously remove anything that is specific to your project. But this essentially will export all fields and entries from a passed in `sectionHandle` as a URL Param.

```
{# @var craft \craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable #}
{# @var section \craft\models\Section #}
{% requireLogin %}
{% spaceless %}

    {# Set the section from the optional sectionHandle param, defaulting to 'answers' #}
    {% set section = 'answers' %}
    {% set sectionHandle = craft.app.request.getParam('sectionHandle') %}
    {% if sectionHandle | length %}
        {% set section = sectionHandle %}
    {% endif %}

    {# Get all of the fields from the layout for the CSV header #}
    {% set csvHeader = [] %}
    {% set fields = craft.sections.sectionByHandle(section).getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
    {% for field in fields %}
        {% set csvHeader = csvHeader | merge([field.name]) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {# Get all of the entry content for the CSV data #}
    {% set csvData = [] %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section(section).all() %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% set csvRow = [] %}
        {% for field in fields %}
            {% set csvRow = csvRow | merge([entry[field.handle]]) %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% set csvData = csvData | merge([csvRow]) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {# Output the data as a CSV file #}
    {% set options = {
        header: csvHeader,
        rows: csvData
    } %}
    {{ craft.beam.csv(options) }}
{% endspaceless %}
```

...enjoy. This is what was used (with a few additions) in the project: [Post-Mortem: LinkedIn Talent Intelligence Experience](https://nystudio107.com/blog/post-mortem-linkedin-talent-intelligence-experience)